# Page View Controller :custom page slider

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a feature using `PageViewController` in iOS Swift language. In my scenario there will be images on all views associated with `PageViewController`. I will have buttons on top of images, (refer to example app's screenshot.) How can I implement that with change of page only the image slides not the buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to do it, by following steps:

1. In your storyboard, create a standard Viewcontroller scene.
2. To this scene add your fixed buttons and a container view. Adding
   the container view will automatically add an embedded view
   controller. Select this and delete it.
3. Drag a Page view controller into the storyboard.
4. Select the container view and drag from the "viewDidLoad" item in
   its "triggered segues" list to the page view controller. Select
   "Embed" as the segue type.

Comment: Accept your answer as answer, so that it won't be unanswered

Answer (score 0):

Following delegate methods are to display dots of page controller, dots will appear at bottom of view.

1. `presentationCountForPageViewController`
2. `presentationIndexForPageViewController`

For your requirement need to create custom `UIButton`group or `UIView` group, so that you can place it anywhere in page.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you provide and tutorial or documentation as how to do this?